# IMPORTING the AdRequest , AdSize and AdView on Android studio

Tags: android

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;  
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;  
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

How can in fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

try to restart everything and it works now
i mean restart eclipse or Android studio